# Can I clean dust from a scratched sensor?

Tags: sensor, cleaning

I have a camera with a scratched sensor (a Canon 1Ds Mk II) - can I clean the dust from the sensor? And if yes, how? By using the wet method? Or just by blowing air?

The scratch is in the middle. Perhaps it is better to avoid that area?

Comment: Do you mean that you have *both* a scratch *and* some dust on your sensor, and you would like to remove the dust without causing any further damage?

Comment: @Jukka: Yes. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I like the idea of using trying to use a rocket blower to remove a scratch! :-)

Comment: Note that you cannot scratch *the sensor itself* without seriously breaking things. What you have scratched is the sensor's cover-glass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not particular familiar with that specific camera but I would suggest taking it in to get the glass cover replaced. There are companies that specialises in such things. Check this thread out for details: http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/topic/664948.

In all likelihood the scratch will be on the glass directly above the sensor rather than on the sensor itself, so it shouldn't be massively expensive.

Comment: better yet, take it to an authorised dealer and have it sent in for repair and cleaning. But do ask a quote first in case it's indeed the sensor itself in which case the repair might be more expensive than replacing the camera unless it's a highend body (which this is of course).

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too - and it is worth getting a no-obligation quote - but according to the thread on fredmiranda.com (above) Canon have in some cases decided to replace the entire sensor even when the scratch is on the protective glass. Hence the recommendation to look at third-party options.

Comment: @vlad259 - That's probably because replacing the cover-glass is really involved. It's epoxy-bonded to the sensor's ceramic casing. You need a clean-room and some really aggressive solvents to remove the glass, and it's rather hard to do without damaging anything else.

Comment: I would wonder if it would be possible to lap the scratch away. It's just an idea, but It should e possible to simply polish the surface of the glass away until the scratch is gone. It would be very time consuming though. Probably not cost-effective, and glass-lapping is something of a black art anyways.

Comment: @FakeName not to mention it would change the plane of focus.

Comment: @Evan Krall - Well, no matter what you do, you are probably going to have to recalibrate the autofocus, so yeah....

Comment: These people will do it for you - I don't know what they're like but they are one of the companies out there that can replace them: http://shop.lifepixel.com/3-Scratched-sensor-filter-replacement-service/Scratched-sensor-filter-replacement-service-p64.html